# How Would You Describe Someone With No Limbs?

Tags: word-choice

Certain characters in certain media have no limbs.  That is to say, they have a head, a body, hands and feet, but lack the parts attaching those various bits of their body.  A good visual example would be the video game character [Rayman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayman_%28character%29).

"Disembodied" and "Limbless" are both good words for such a character, but the former is a bit too extreme, and the latter might be mistaken as a lack of arm AND hand, or a lack of leg AND foot.

Is there a word to describe this kind of character and their relation to their body/body parts?

Comment: Something relating to potato figures, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe. It is somewhat Mr. Potato Head Esque, though I'm specifically curious about figures whose appendages are all in the right place, just without the...appending parts.

Comment: Not a single word, but I'd describe him as having *free-floating appendages*.  Now all you have to do is find someone who knows German who can put that together into a single "word" and then borrow it into English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might refer to Rayman as *[ethereally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethereally)-limbed* or *invisibly-limbed*; or perhaps call him *[disjointed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disjointed#Adjective)*, a word that means “(figuratively) Not connected, coherent, or continuous”.  (It appears that Rayman is missing all his arm and leg joints, as well as his neck.)

Comment: Seems like the best answer I'll get.  Thank you.  I also like "ethereally-limbed".